# Show that the expression is a unit in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]$

Tags: number-theory

**Problem:** Show that $3+\sqrt{10}$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]$.

**My Work:** I'm trying to find a multiplicative inverse for $3+\sqrt{10}$ by solving $(3+\sqrt{10})v = \sqrt{10}$ but solving for $v$ does not give me an integer or multiple of $\sqrt{10}$. I feel that my approach/understanding is wrong, could I get advice on this?

Comment: You need to consider
$$\frac1{3+\sqrt{10}}.$$
Do you know about "rationalising the denominator"?

Comment: You don't want $(3 + \sqrt{10})v = \sqrt{10}$.  You want $(3 + \sqrt{10})v = 1$.

Comment: When I solve the latter for v I get v = √10 - 3. Is this in Z[root 10] since 3 = 3(root 10)^0 and the sum of elements in Z[root 10] is an element in Z[root 10]?

Comment: Yes, the $v$ you got is correct

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $v$ need not be an integer or an integer multiple of $\sqrt{10}$ -- it may be a combination of both!

Answer (score 0):

A slightly elaborate solution consists in using a bit of ANT. Specifically, because $10\equiv 2\pmod 4$, the ring of integers of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt 10)$ is $\mathbf Z[\sqrt 10]$, so $x=3+\sqrt 10$ is a unit iff $N(x)=\pm1$, where $N$ is the norm map. This is the case since $(3+\sqrt 10)(3-\sqrt 10)=-1$. If you don't want any ANT, then the above norm computation shows directly that $(3+\sqrt 10)(-3+\sqrt 10)=1$ .